# Shell redirection: Command doesn't appear to output to stdout or stderr

Tags: bash

With all the questions and answers about redirecting shell streams, I'm surprised I'm posting one of my own, but I can't seem to find anything similar online.

To describe my situation simply, I am trying to write a bash script that will run a particular binary app and watch the output for particular strings so that it may act on them.

I was able to achieve the desired functionality with a test script that was standing in for my binary app. However, when running against the real thing, it does not seem to capture all output. When I run the binary app alone, it outputs as such

```
status OK
something A
something B
...
something Z
status OK
something A
```

But when I try to redirect this output for analysis, I only get the "status OK" lines. All the good stuff in between is absent. This is true even if I try to redirect it to a file with > . At first I thought it may put "status" on stdout and the "something"s on stderr, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

If this app is able to output stuff to the terminal that I can read, how am I not able to capture it? Is it possible the formatting is strange such that it is interpreted correctly by the terminal display, but somehow not by any kind of redirection?

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: It really depends on what the binary app is doing. It might be sending output to /dev/tty. It might be checking stdout and/or stderr to see if they're terminal devices. It might... be doing almost anything.

Comment: @Cyrus I am unable to post the exact code for legal reasons, but nevertheless, the vital details are hidden in the binary app and I don't have the source code. My question is primarily to understand what are the possible ways that an app can output text to the terminal in a way that is not able to be redirected via > or 2> . But yeah, I understand it's a pretty open-ended question.

Comment: Do you have access to tools like `strace` or `truss`?  If so, run the app using them, saving the output (which goes to stderr by default).  In there you should see the kernel APIs used to write the output and you'll be able to see if it is using stdout (`write(1, ...)`) or stderr (`write(2,...`))  or maybe using the terminal APIs direct.  Do a `man termios` to see some of the terminal interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gordon Davisson is right on the money. It appears the output was being sent directly to /dev/tty, which apparently is a thing people do... Thanks, Gordon!

**Update:** Upon further tinkering and input from others, it looks like the important part is using `script` to capture all the output. Additional redirection (ie. `2>&1`) is not necessary, but can be done if need be. Continue below to see it in action.

Here's my basic code:

The binary app that sends data to /dev/tty is called 'binApp', and let's say it takes an arbitrary number of command line arguments. My wrapper/watcher script will be run with binApp and all its args, like so:

`WrapScript binApp arg1 arg2 ... argn`

WrapScript:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=("$@")
cmd=`echo "${args[@]:0}"`

run() {
    script -q -c "$cmd" 2>&1 | while read -r line; do
        if [ "$line" = "$badthing" ]; then
            echo "restarting..."
            break
        fi
        echo "$line"
    done
}

badthing="ERROR"

while true; do
    run
    sleep 0.5
done
```

The `sleep 0.5` allows user to press "Ctrl+c" twice to exit.

Comment: Your definition starts with a `{` and ends with a `done` -- that's surely not right. And consider avoiding the `function` keyword in favor of POSIX-compliant function definition syntax, which is just `run() {` with no `function` preceding; that way your code will work with a wider range of shells.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `/dev/null>&1` you should put `2>&1`. This will redirect the stderr to the stdout and you will see both in any way you'll run it.

Comment: For some reason I thought the `/dev/null>&1` was the magic bullet that was making this all work, but I tried `2>&1` as well as not using any redirection, and they all seemed to work! Seems like it's really `script` that's doing all the work. Thanks!